# Running empty Android program - is this behavior expected?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I'm learning the basics of Android development and I've ran into some issues with setting up the programming environment. Now I've created a new Android Application Project and I'm running it using my phone. When I do, I get an error message on my phone: "Unfortunately, HelloWorld has stopped." and I'm not sure if it's supposed to or not, considering that I've done absolutely nothing to the project files. Here is the LogCat output in its entirety:

```
03-10 18:34:16.264: D/dalvikvm(2673): Late-enabling CheckJNI
03-10 18:34:16.361: W/dalvikvm(2673): VFY: unable to resolve static field 1559 (ActionBarWindow) in Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$styleable;
03-10 18:34:16.361: D/dalvikvm(2673): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0004
03-10 18:34:16.364: D/AndroidRuntime(2673): Shutting down VM
03-10 18:34:16.364: W/dalvikvm(2673): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416d7d40)
03-10 18:34:16.368: E/AndroidRuntime(2673): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-10 18:34:16.368: E/AndroidRuntime(2673): Process: com.example.helloworld, PID: 2673
03-10 18:34:16.368: E/AndroidRuntime(2673): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable
03-10 18:34:16.368: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:107)
03-10 18:34:16.368: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:58)
03-10 18:34:16.368: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
03-10 18:34:16.368: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at com.example.helloworld.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
03-10 18:34:16.368: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
03-10 18:34:16.368: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
03-10 18:34:16.368: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2173)
03-10 18:34:16.368: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
03-10 18:34:16.368: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
03-10 18:34:16.368: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
03-10 18:34:16.368: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-10 18:34:16.368: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-10 18:34:16.368: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
03-10 18:34:16.368: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-10 18:34:16.368: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-10 18:34:16.368: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
03-10 18:34:16.368: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
03-10 18:34:16.368: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-10 18:34:18.259: I/Process(2673): Sending signal. PID: 2673 SIG: 9
03-10 18:36:57.062: W/dalvikvm(2984): VFY: unable to resolve static field 1559 (ActionBarWindow) in Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$styleable;
03-10 18:36:57.063: D/dalvikvm(2984): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0004
03-10 18:36:57.064: D/AndroidRuntime(2984): Shutting down VM
03-10 18:36:57.064: W/dalvikvm(2984): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416d7d40)
03-10 18:36:57.066: E/AndroidRuntime(2984): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-10 18:36:57.066: E/AndroidRuntime(2984): Process: com.example.helloworld, PID: 2984
03-10 18:36:57.066: E/AndroidRuntime(2984): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable
03-10 18:36:57.066: E/AndroidRuntime(2984):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:107)
03-10 18:36:57.066: E/AndroidRuntime(2984):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:58)
03-10 18:36:57.066: E/AndroidRuntime(2984):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
03-10 18:36:57.066: E/AndroidRuntime(2984):     at com.example.helloworld.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
03-10 18:36:57.066: E/AndroidRuntime(2984):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
03-10 18:36:57.066: E/AndroidRuntime(2984):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
03-10 18:36:57.066: E/AndroidRuntime(2984):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2173)
03-10 18:36:57.066: E/AndroidRuntime(2984):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
03-10 18:36:57.066: E/AndroidRuntime(2984):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
03-10 18:36:57.066: E/AndroidRuntime(2984):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
03-10 18:36:57.066: E/AndroidRuntime(2984):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-10 18:36:57.066: E/AndroidRuntime(2984):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-10 18:36:57.066: E/AndroidRuntime(2984):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
03-10 18:36:57.066: E/AndroidRuntime(2984):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-10 18:36:57.066: E/AndroidRuntime(2984):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-10 18:36:57.066: E/AndroidRuntime(2984):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
03-10 18:36:57.066: E/AndroidRuntime(2984):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
03-10 18:3

6:57.066: E/AndroidRuntime(2984):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

So, is this normal behavior or have I done something wrong while setting up Eclipse, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the Android compatibility library is not correctly configured for your project. In Eclipse, right click on the project in the package explorer and select `Android Tools > Add Support Library`. After setting up the support library, clean and rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior when reporting an error with your application.